# What is the issue of select() using so much CPU power?

Tags: sockets, tcp, posix-select

I am writing a network communication program using non-blocking sockets (C/C++) and `select`. The program is pretty big, so I cannot upload source code. In a very aggressive testing session, I use testing code to open and close both TCP and UDP frequently. It always ends up that one end does not respond and has CPU usage over 98 or 99%. Then I use **gdb** to attach. "bt" shows the following:

```
0x00007f1b71b59ac3 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
```

What type of error could it be?

```
$ uname -a
Linux kiosk2 2.6.32-34-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 19:39:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: So, what was the issue?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's impossible to say without looking at the code, but often when a select-based loop starts spinning at ~100% CPU usage, it's because one or more of the sockets you told `select()` to watch are ready-for-read (and/or ready-for-write) so that `select()` returns right away instead of blocking... but then the code neglects to actually `recv()` (or `send()`) any data on that socket.  After failing to read/write anything, your event loop would try to go back to sleep by calling `select()` again, but of course the socket's data (or buffer space, in the ready-for-write case) is still there waiting to be handled, so `select()` returns immediately again, the buggy code neglects to do the `recv()` (or `send()`) again, and around and around we go at top speed :)

Another possibility would be that you are passing in a timeout value to `select()` that is either zero or near-zero, causing `select()` to return very quickly even when no sockets are ready-for-anything... that often happens when people forget to re-initialize the timeval struct before each call to `select()`.  You need to re-initialize the timeval struct each time because some implementations of `select()` will modify it before returning.

My suggestion is to put some printf's (or your favorite equivalent) immediately before and immediately after your call to `select()`, and watch that output as you reproduce the fault.  That will show you whether the spinning is happening inside of a single call to `select()`, or if something is causing `select()` to return immediately over and over again.

Comment: +1 one of the best answers on SO that I've seen when there's no source code in the question

Comment: mister, you are a savior